# Hall effect at finite temperature in conventional metals

Tags: magnetic-fields, metals, fermi-liquids

There are lots of measurements showing strong temperature ($T$) dependence of Hall coefficient ($R_H$) in correlated materials (eg. cuprate superconductors and other oxide materials) and such plots are available in many recent experimental papers. However, I could not find any $R_H$ vs $T$ plot for a conventional metal more or less devoid of disorder/impurity effects.

Is there any such paper or textbook available? Also is there any reference that shows how Hall angle or its cotangent behaves with temperature in a conventional Fermi liquid metal?

Comment: The charge carrier density in metals is almost temperature independent.

Comment: @Farcher That I know. I've been looking for experimental evidences.

Comment: The experimental results do exist, you just have to look for them.  Try http://documentslide.com/documents/hall-coefficient-of-technically-pure-metals-from-80-k-to-800k.html

Comment: @Farcher Thanks, but still the plots show significant temperature dependence. The samples are not clean too! I wonder why such an experiment never appeared on a standard textbook page!